# SwiftUI View stops updating when application goes to background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm using the Spotify APK to authorize a connection to the Spotify app. All communication with Spotify is done via the Scene Delegate. My issue is that when I call for authorization and I'm taken to and from the Spotify app, the current view seems to stop updating with @Published variable changes. However, I want the view to change upon successful authorization/connection.

I've tried having the MainView update with different changes to different variables, but it seems that no matter what I do, the view stops updating with changes to published variables once the app leaves and reenters the foreground.

SceneDelegate:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate, SPTAppRemoteDelegate, SPTAppRemotePlayerStateDelegate {

    @ObservedObject var MainVM = MainViewModel()

    func appRemoteDidEstablishConnection(_ appRemote: SPTAppRemote) {
        MainVM.viewSwitch = false
    }

}
```

MainViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var viewSwitch: Bool = true

    var appRemote: SPTAppRemote {
        get {
            let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first
            let sd : SceneDelegate = (scene?.delegate as? SceneDelegate)!
            return sd.appRemote
        }
    }

    func connectAppRemote() {
        appRemote.authorizeAndPlayURI("")
    }

}
```

MainView:

```
struct MainView: View {

    @ObservedObject var MainVM = MainViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        if MainVM.viewSwitch {
            Text("View 1 Displayed")
        } else {
            Text("View 2 Displayed")
        }
    }
    .onAppear {
        MainVM.connectAppRemote()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Vincent, I just started working on a SwiftUI app and came across this question. How did you get the framework to install? I have the bridging header linked up but a get an error `"Extra info about plist: ACL=<not found>" ` when I build and run. Did you experience this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You work with different objects:

A. `SceneDelegate` has own instance (btw, here you don't need `ObservedObject`)

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate, 
                     SPTAppRemoteDelegate, SPTAppRemotePlayerStateDelegate {

    @ObservedObject var MainVM = MainViewModel()
```

and

B. `MainView` has own

```
struct MainView: View {

    @ObservedObject var MainVM = MainViewModel() // << recreated
```

You need to pass that one in `SceneDelegate` as `environmentObject` in `MainView`, like

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, 
           options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    let contentView = MainView().environmentObject(MainVM)
```

and declare it correspondingly

```
struct MainView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var MainVM: MainViewModel
```